# Wildcard usage for ^

Tags: sql, sql-server, char, numbers, wildcard

I want to verify a field,

1. if a field is only number like 12345, return nothing
2. if a field is something like 1234-1, or -123331, return nothing
3. if a field is a12341, or 34j123 or 99933hh return 1
4. if a field is a1234-, or sodf233- return 1.

Basically just check if there is a non number character in this field, but allow the dash to be in.

Here is my thoughts:

```
select 1
from dbo.random.field
where ISNUMBERIC(field)=0 and field not like '%-%'
```

Use this to check if there is letter, and then, if there is a -, but my test case always like this:

1. 12345 Pass
2. 12345a Failed
3. 12345- Pass
4. 1234a- Pass, but this should fail.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume you are using SQL Server, based on `isnumeric()`.  You can use `like`:

```
where field like 'a%[0-9]%' and
      field not like 'a%[^-0-9]%'
```

The first checks that the column starts with `'a'` and has at least one digit.  The second checks that there are no non-digits or non-hyphens after the `'a'`.

You can generalize the `a` to any letter using `[a-z]` (assuming case insensitivity) or to any non-digit using `[^0-9]`.

EDIT:

For your revised question, you just seem to want a letter.  You can use:

```
select *
from (values ('12345'), ('1234-1'), ('1234-1'), ('a12341'), ('34j123'), ('99933hh'), ('a1234-'), ('sodf233-')) v(field)
where field like '%[^-0-9]%';
```

Comment: Sir, Please read the question one more time.

Comment: is like a12345 will fail, and 123df34 will fail as well. Not started with a

Comment: @ZechengLi . . . I edited the answer to match the current version of the question.  Please do not change the question again.  Ask a *new* question with clear sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Comment: thanks sir.
Would you please help me with one more question here? How can I verify if a field is like  number hyphens number number number number number, AKA something like 1-12345 will pass, but 1-1234 will not pass, only a number in the front, then hyphens and 5 number later will pass, what should I use here? 

I'd tried where field like '[0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  is this correct?

Comment: @ZechengLi. . . Please ask this as a new question.  The way you describe it in the comment is good.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did in the end

```
like '%[^-0-9]%'
```